# Cant `Insert Image`

Tags: xmpp, pidgin

Pidgin has an option to `Insert Image`, but when I use XMPP this feature is not available

[image]

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Although XMPP supports images it's up to the plugins to have the protocol-specific code written for each:

> [The only protocols that support the "Insert Image" function in Pidgin are GG, ICQ, MXit, MySpace, Sametime, SILC and AIM. Other protocols, including IRC, Bonjour, Yahoo Messenger, MSN and XMPP, support file transfers but not direct image transfers.](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/i-cant-send-pictures-in-pidgin)

People have asked about this in the past, but it looked like only [AIM's plugin had support](https://pidgin.im/pipermail/support/2013-May/026731.html).

For a time it seemed this was going to be rectified, but ostensibly nothing's been done with [this ticket in 17months](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/10056)..